# Flutter Scheduled Notification Not Showing Up

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, push-notification

I am using the flutter local plugin to schedule notifications. I have set it up such that it sends me a notification when I call :

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, 'Hello Buddy', 'A message from flutter buddy', platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'test payload');
```

And, it sends me a push notifications with the expected contents immediately! However, when I use :

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        0, 'Hello Buddy', 'A message from flutter buddy', DateTime.now()+Duration(seconds: 5), platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'test payload', androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
```

The notification is not sent... I looked at the other questions on stack overflow regarding this though the replies were irrelevant. Below is my android manifest and I would really appreciate it if you could assist me with this! Thanks a lot and I really apperciate your help:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.email_test">
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="email_test"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
          
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```